# Kafka: Continuously getting FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND

Tags: apache-kafka

I am continuously getting FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. I'm not sure why its happening. Can anyone please me here what is the problem and what will be the impact on consumers and brokers.

Kafka Server Log:

```
INFO [2019-10-18 12:09:00,709] [ReplicaFetcherThread-1-8][] org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=6, leaderId=8, fetcherId=1] Node 8 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=258818904, epoch=2233): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
 INFO [2019-10-18 12:09:01,078] [ReplicaFetcherThread-44-10][] org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=6, leaderId=10, fetcherId=44] Node 10 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=518415741, epoch=4416): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
 INFO [2019-10-18 12:09:01,890] [ReplicaFetcherThread-32-9][] org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=6, leaderId=9, fetcherId=32] Node 9 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=418200413, epoch=3634): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
```

Kafka Consumer Log:

```
12:29:58,936 INFO  [FetchSessionHandler:383] [Consumer clientId=bannerGroupMap#87e2af7cf742#test, groupId=bannerGroupMap#87e2af7cf742#test] Node 8 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1368981303, epoch=60): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
12:29:58,937 INFO  [FetchSessionHandler:383] [Consumer clientId=bannerGroupMap#87e2af7cf742#test, groupId=bannerGroupMap#87e2af7cf742#test] Node 3 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1521862194, epoch=59): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
12:29:59,939 INFO  [FetchSessionHandler:383] [Consumer clientId=zoneGroupMap#87e2af7cf742#test, groupId=zoneGroupMap#87e2af7cf742#test] Node 7 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=868804875, epoch=58): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
12:30:06,952 INFO  [FetchSessionHandler:383] [Consumer clientId=creativeMap#87e2af7cf742#test, groupId=creativeMap#87e2af7cf742#test] Node 3 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1135396084, epoch=58): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
12:30:12,965 INFO  [FetchSessionHandler:383] [Consumer clientId=creativeMap#87e2af7cf742#test, groupId=creativeMap#87e2af7cf742#test] Node 6 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1346340004, epoch=56): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
```

Cluster Details:

```
Broker: 13 (1 Broker : 14 cores & 36GB memory)
Kafka cluster version: 2.0.0
Kafka Java client version: 2.0.0
Number topics: ~15. 
Number of consumers: 7K (all independent and manually assigned all partitions of a topic to a consumers. One consumer is consuming all partitions from a topic only)
```

Comment: I am getting this same error with Kafka Java client version 2.3.1.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @BertS.increase this value `max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots`

Comment: Hi @HrishikeshMishra was this (above comment) the solution you found for this problem? Would you consider in adding it as an answer to your post and if all possible with a little bit of explanation. I'm having the same issue, I will test your above solution.

Comment: This is an INFO log.  What are the implications of just ignoring it?

Comment: How can a consumer recover from this never ending loop? I am using Springs KafkaListner and it does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Increase the value of `max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots`. The default value is 1K, in my case I have increased it to 10K and it fixed.

Comment: Is this a setting on the broker?

Comment: Yes, its broker setting

Comment: Is there something that can be done on the consumer or producer side?

Comment: Not required anything at producer and consumer end.

Comment: I see the error on my consumer.  I don't have access to modify the broker itself.  Should this be a concern for me?

Comment: As far as I remember, this error comes on consumer only. And its INFO, should not be problem. But not 100% confident. You can your broker maintainer to increase this.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an error, it's INFO and it's telling you that you are connected but it can't fetch a session id because there's none to fetch.

It's normal to see this message and the flushing message in the log.

Comment: +1

"Whenever the fetch session has a cache miss on the broker, the client logs FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND at the info level. This message isn't actionable to clients, and does not actually indicate an error. More accurately, it possibly indicates that the broker is sub-optimally configured." - a defect in Kafka Github

Answer (score 1):

I have increased it at first from 1K to 2K, and in the second step from 2K to 4K, and as long as the limit was not exhausted, there was no appearance of error:

[image]

[image]

As it seemed to me like a session leak by certain unidentified consumer, I didn't try 10K limit yet, but reading Hrishikesh Mishra's answer, I definitely will. Because, increasing the limit also decreased the frequency of error, so the question of identifying individual consumer groups that are opening excessive number of incremental fetch sessions, mentioned here [How to check the actual number of incremental fetch session cache slots used in Kafka cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630876/how-to-check-the-actual-number-of-incremental-fetch-session-cache-slots-used-in) , may be irrelevant in the end.