# Why FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I got lots of lots of `FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND`

```
INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=1, fetcherId=2] Node 1 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1229568311, epoch=511): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=1, fetcherId=5] Node 1 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=136816338, epoch=504): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=0, fetcherId=2] Node 0 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=311282207, epoch=569): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
...
```

I read [Kafka: Continuously getting FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484342/kafka-continuously-getting-fetch-session-id-not-found) and [How to check the actual number of incremental fetch session cache slots used in Kafka cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630876/how-to-check-the-actual-number-of-incremental-fetch-session-cache-slots-used-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)

For now, we just got metrics about lags from [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow).

My questions:

1, Can someone explain why I got so many `FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND`? what does it mean? I did not get them before.

Some consumers send too many requests? or the leaders always re-elected?

I have no idea. Could some give me more details?

2, If it is because some consumers send too many requests, how to identify these consumers?

Thanks

Comment: Show your broker and consumer configs, please. You can use TCPdump and Wireshark to watch network requests

Comment: Can you also check what the values of the metrics mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630876/how-to-check-the-actual-number-of-incremental-fetch-session-cache-slots-used-in?noredirect=1&lq=1 are?