# @KafkaListener not recovering after DisconnectException

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer (Spring boot) configured using *@KafkaListener*. This was running in production and all was good until as part of the maintenance the brokers were restarted. By docs, I was expecting that the kafka listener would recover once broker is back up. However this is not what I observed from the logs. The logs stopped with following Exception:

```
2020-04-22 11:11:28,802|INFO|automator-consumer-app-id-0-C-1|org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler|[Consumer clientId=automator-consumer-app-id-0, groupId=automator-consumer-app-id] Node 10 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=2138208872, epoch=348): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
2020-04-22 11:24:23,798|INFO|automator-consumer-app-id-0-C-1|org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler|[Consumer clientId=automator-consumer-app-id-0, groupId=automator-consumer-app-id] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=499459047, epoch=314160) to node 7: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
2020-04-22 11:36:37,241|INFO|automator-consumer-app-id-0-C 1|org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler|[Consumer clientId=automator-consumer-app-id-0, groupId=automator-consumer-app-id] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=2033512553, epoch=342949) to node 4: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
```

**Once the application was restarted, the connectivity reestablished. I was wondering if this could be related with any of the consumer configuration below.**

```
2020-04-22 12:46:59,681|INFO|main|org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig|ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [msk-e00-br1.int.bell.ca:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = automator-consumer-app-id-0
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = automator-consumer-app-id
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the value of

> max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots

. The default value is 1K. You can refer the answer here : [How to check the actual number of incremental fetch session cache slots used in Kafka cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630876/how-to-check-the-actual-number-of-incremental-fetch-session-cache-slots-used-in)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your application is continuously listening the messages from the topic, suppose if there is no message published in the topic you will get this type of exception.

**org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null**

[Disconnect Exception class](http://www.howsoftworks.net/kafkclie/DisconnectException)

If we start sending messages to topic, application will start running and consume those messages.

Here you need to increase the request timeout in your properties files.

**consumer.request.timeout.ms:**

Comment: Apologies for responding so late and thank you for taking time out to help. This is the behavior what I expected too. However since the broker was down for a little too long and the consumer got disconnect. But I was expecting this to be reconnected as soon as the broker is back. However this was not the case as the session was evicted when the broker came back up. Had to do with the settings for `heartbeat.interval.ms`, `session.timeout.ms` and `max.poll.interval.ms`