# Apache Flink & Kafka FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND info logs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Our Flink application has a Kafka datasource.

Application is run with 32 parallelism.

When I look at the logs, I see a lot of statements about FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.

```
2020-05-04 11:04:47,753 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler                  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-81, groupId=sampleGroup]
Node 26 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=439766827, epoch=42): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
2020-05-04 11:04:48,230 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler                  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-78, groupId=sampleGroup]
Node 28 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=281654250, epoch=42): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
```

What do these log statements mean?

What are the possible negative effects?

> Not: I have no experience with Apache Kafka

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen for a few reasons but the most common one is the FetchSession cache being full on the brokers.

By default, brokers cache up to 1000 FetchSessions (configured via `max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots`). When this fills up, brokers cam evict cache entries. If your client cache entry is gone, it will received the `FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND` error.

This error is not fatal and consumers should send a new full FetchRequest automatically and keep working.

You can check the size of the FetchSession cache using the `kafka.server:type=FetchSessionCache,name=NumIncrementalFetchSessions` metric.

Comment: thanks for the answer, "This error is not fatal and consumers should send...", I have look at the logs again I saw the same consumer clientId gives the same info within small interval. For example "Consumer clientId=consumer-84" said FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND at times "2020-05-06 00:58:18,769", "2020-05-06 01:00:19,500", "2020-05-06 01:04:25,887". Can this be a considered normal behaviour or can it cause some latency?

Comment: It will affect latency a bit as it forces the consumer to do a full fetch request again

Comment: is there any solution for this problem ? From this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484342/kafka-continuously-getting-fetch-session-id-not-found , it is said increase the value of "max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots"