# Unable to process fetch requests in Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am using Spring boot and Kafka (not Spring Kafka) to consume messages generated from producers on the topic. This is working fine with no issue as such. What I am trying to understand is the below messages. Whenever something is getting produced, I am able to read it based on my logic and for now, just printing it on console. But, when nothing is getting produced, then I am keep getting below messages. It's not causing any failure. Please help me to understand what does it mean. Do I need to do something to handle it? I am using Kafka version 2.4.0.

```
2020-07-06 17:30:22.295  INFO 12908 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group12-1, groupId=group12] Node 72 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=725943037, epoch=240): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
    2020-07-06 17:32:29.957  INFO 12908 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group12-1, groupId=group12] Node 72 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=541437574, epoch=162): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
    2020-07-06 17:34:32.871  INFO 12908 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group12-1, groupId=group12] Node 72 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=559071905, epoch=155): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
    2020-07-06 17:36:43.513  INFO 12908 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group12-1, groupId=group12] Node 72 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=225929150, epoch=166): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
    2020-07-06 17:38:52.561  INFO 12908 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group12-1, groupId=group12] Node 72 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1829710146, epoch=164): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
    2020-07-06 17:44:07.219  INFO 12908 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group12-1, groupId=group12] Node 72 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1766828327, epoch=396): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
```

Comment: You might have to increase the value of `max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots`. It's default value is 1K, You can have it increased in broker setting to get this sorted.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484342/kafka-continuously-getting-fetch-session-id-not-found

Comment: Thanks Amit and Java Techincal. But, it seems like nothing can be done at the consumer side to handle it.